# higher order function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am reading the book Eloquent to learn javascript. I came across this example

```
function unless(test, then) {
    if (!test) then();
}

function repeat(times, body) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times ; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function (n) {
    unless(n % 2, function () {
        console.log(n, " is even ");
    });
});

// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

I know functions can be passed as arguments and can be inside one another.
But are `then()` and `body()` functions? Where are they defined? What's the value of `n`?

Comment: `then` and `body` are just the names given to the arguments. The code assumes they are functions (and will fail nastily if you pass them something else) and calls them. In this case, since they *are* functions, it works just fine. They are defined in the argument list of the *call* itself.

Comment: what's the value of n? and if they're declaring " function ( n ) ",isn't the function supposed to have a name? same with the parameter of unless!

Comment: *"what's the value of `n`?"* Whatever is passed to the function. Look at where the function is called. *"isn't the function supposed to have a name"* No, functions don't have to have a name. How parameters work doesn't suddenly change when you pass a function. Simplest example: `function foo(n) { console.log(n); }; foo(5); foo(function() {});`. In the first call, `n` will have the value `5`, in the second call `n` will refer to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little explanation.

```
function unless ( test , then ) {
  if (! test ) then () ;
}
function repeat ( times , body ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < times ; i ++) body ( i ) ;
}

// in here you also pass 2 params to repeat.
// 3 and an anonymous function, the function is the argument 'body' in repeat
repeat (3 , function ( n ) {
  // as you can see here - you pass 2 params to unless, 
  // 1 is the result of n %2, and an anonymous  function, the function is the argument
  // "then" in unless.
  unless ( n % 2 , function () {
    console . log (n , " is even ") ;

  }) ;
}) ;
```

the value of n is changing from 0 to 3 it, its going to be 0,1,2

Also since your a beginner i would suggest using https://jsfiddle.net/ to test stuff out.

Answer (score 3):

> but are `then()` and `body()` functions?

`then` and `body` are parameters. Their values depend on the values that are passed to `unless` and `repeat`. So in order to determine what the values are (i.e. whether they are functions or not) you need to look at where `unless` and `repeat` are called and which values are passed to them.

Keep in mind that, in general, `repeat` and `unless` can be called multiple times. The values of `then` and `body` can be different for every function call, but they will have to be of the type (number, string, function, ...) the function expects, otherwise it won't work correctly.

> Where are they defined?

In your example, `repeat` and `unless` are called here:

```
repeat(3, function (n) {
    unless(n % 2, function () {
        document.write(n + " is even<br>");
    });
});
```

You can see that the second arguments passed to `repeat` and `unless` are indeed functions.

> What's the value of `n`?

Lets have a look where the function is called. The function is passed as second argument to `repeat`. `repeat` uses `body` to refer to the second argument and it laters calls it as `body(i)` in a loop. `i` will have the values `0` to `times - 1`. `times` is the first argument passed to `repeat` which in your example is `3`. So the function will be called multiple (three) times, receiving the values `0`, `1` and `2`.

Comment: Was just about to post something like that, perhaps worth to mention that if he is familiar with other languages he may interprete "body" and "then" as anonymous functions? upvote anyway, well explained and clearly answers to the op's questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your example here you have the signature of the `unless` function:

```
function unless ( test , then ) {
// code here
}
```

both **test** and **then** are called parameters and change depending on the arguments you pass when you call `unless`

for example :

```
 function first(){}
 function second(){}

 unless(first,second)
```

means that **test** inside the unless is a function cause 
**test** is replaced with **first function** and **then** is replaced with the **second function** when calling `unless`

```
// unless(test,then) => unless(first,second)
//         |     |              |        |
//         |-----|---------------        |     
//               ------------------------|
```